# Image stops scaling with bootstrap-responsive.css at the smallest level

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm making my first website using Twitter Bootstrap, and am trying to understand why the logo image on my page stops scaling and jumps in size once the screen size reaches a small enough size.

The current behavior makes the site look horrendous on the iPhone.

The image file itself is a 200 x 500 px .gif

Here is a jsfiddle with the code in it:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/eugip9/uyGH9

And here is the code from the div it's in:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1">
    <img src="./HomePage/logo-02.gif" center alt>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left;padding-top: 5em;text-indent: 5em;"; class="span11">
        <h1>Site Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image scales well down to a point, but once the screen gets small enough the image goes back to 200px x 500px

I'm using the default bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: This type of questions are better with a JsFiddle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/uyGH9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every span has a 100% width when the screen is less than 767px. So, due to every image of the theme has a `max-width: 100%` property, you image is resizing when the screen is less than 767px.

I recommend you to resize the image to the desirable width with Photoshop (or similar). It's not always a good idea to resize images with CSS. If you don't want to do that, just put a id to the image and then put a `max-width: 64px` to that logo.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a better way to do a title bar with the logo at the top left in a span 1 and then the title in a span11? Otherwise on the iphone they'll always be stacked vertically, correct?

Comment: @Evan If you don't want to stack the logo in any layout, put a `pull-left` class to the image and put title and image in the same `div.span12`. I believe that should do the work if you resize the image to a smaller size.

Comment: Thank you so much. CSS is still very much a learning experience for me.